# Returning single select instead of multi selects in SQL Server

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to return 3 single values from 3 different tables.

I want to know which of these codes are better considering resource usage and performance (in a stored procedure):

Code 1:

```
declare @acc_cnt int, @selected_item int, @worker_cnt int
select @acc_cnt=count(0) from accounts
select @selected_item=id from items where name='something'
select @worker_cnt=count(0) from workers
select @acc_cnt ,@selected_item,@worker_cnt
```

Code 2:

```
select count(0) from accounts
select id from items where name='something'
select count(0) from workers
```

Is there a difference between returning 3 selects and a single select? I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with C#.  Please explain how it's related to C#, or remove the C# tag.

Comment: well the returned value is handled by c# asp.net. actually i wrote it to help the answerer to know how i would be handling the return values

Comment: I would tell anyone who asked me this question to show me the whole stored procedure and, perhaps, better candidates for performance tuning could be identified. The question is somewhat wasted on only giving us two choices to choose from. For example, has `UNION ALL` `SELECT`s been considered?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 would be *SLIGHTLY* a performance improvement, as you are not declaring the variables and saving a small amount of memory.

Note: The performance improvement would be almost immeasurable.